# Add iterator to id --> R.id.+i+

Tags: android, kotlin

i have 8 checkboxes and i want to know which ones are enabled when button clicked. So first i tried the method below. Checkbox ids: c1, c2, c3...

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener {
            for(i in 1..8){
               var tempId = "R.id.c"+i+""
                if(findViewById<CheckBox>(tempId.toInt()).isEnabled){

                }

            }
}
```

And i got the error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "R.id.c1"

I realized that toInt() method is useless cause tempId contain letters.
 Then i got the checkbox's real id its like this: 2131165251 and change the tempId variable with this. But same error again. 
 Now i did it different way but still curious about why doesn't work method above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Resources.getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String)) to retrieve the id you are looking for

```
val id = resources.getIdentifier("c$i", "id", context.packageName)
```

Comment: Yes it works but too slow... when i click the button i see logs 7-8 secs later. I did with mutableMapOf. Every checkbox has setOnCheckedChangeListener if checkbox checked add it to mutableMap. So i have a list which ones are checked. Thanks for response.